# using C++ and fortran to build R packages, Mac

Tags: c++, r

I have been trying to get an R package downloaded that requires clang and go fortran to be built. I have neither installed on this computer, and since I am using a common computer I do not have the ability to install Xcode.

I downloaded the clang and fortran packages supplied by R at:
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/

After installing them I still get the same error: `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

I am new to creating path modifications and such and wondered if anyone could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that his was not answered still, what I ended up doing was installing clang and gofortran through Homebrew, which worked.